# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int64

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

i took this error on my post methot

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(Order order)
    {
      ...
    }
```

this is my Order and OrderItem Models

```
 public partial class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
        }
        public long OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Pmethod { get; set; }
        public decimal? Gtotal { get; set; }

        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
  public partial class OrderItem
    {
        public long OrderItemId { get; set; }
        public long? OrderId { get; set; }
        public int? ItemId { get; set; }
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my models on angular

```
export class Order {
  orderId: number
  orderNo: string
  customerId: number
  pMethod: string
  gTotal: number
}
export class OrderItem {
  orderItemId:number;
  orderId:number;
  itemId:number;
  quantity:number;
  itemName: string;
  price: number;
  total: number;
}
```

this is my orderService

```
formData:Order;
  orderItems:OrderItem[];
  apiUrl =environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  saveOrUpdateOrder() {
    var body = {
      ...this.formData,
      OrderItems: this.orderItems
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + '/Orders', body);
  }
```

when i tried

```
 var body = JSON.stringify({
      ...this.formData,
      OrderItems: this.orderItems
    });
```

i took this error "Unsupported Media Type"

I tried adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` library it did not work
I added IntToConverter class but it did not work too. Please help me

Comment: Your body variable must be the exact TypeScript order Class. `return this.http.post<Order>(this.apiUrl + '/Orders', myOrder)`

Comment: Note that Angular != AngularJs. You should only tag the one you're using.

Comment: Your TypeScript class is also missing an OrderItems array to correctly match the C# model.

Comment: I tried that but it has not worked yet Carlos

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call JSON.Stringify.

Expand your TypeScript model to

```
export class Order {
  orderId: number
  orderNo: string
  customerId: number
  pMethod: string
  gTotal: number
  orderItems: OrderItem[] //include this
}
```

Then in your apiCall.
`this.formData.orderItems = this.orderItems`

`return this.http.post<Order>(this.apiUrl + '/Orders', formData);`